# how to store a mutually exclusive value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Based on social networking design, I need to store whether a person has `Liked` or `Disliked` something. There are other actions they can take such as `Share` as well.

What I need to do is make sure that when a person `Like`s something, its value is stored as `true`. But if they then change their mind and `Dislike` the same thing, that the `Like`'d value is set to `NULL` and the `Dislike` value is set to `true`.

Initial approach would be a table like this:

```
UserID (int) | ItemID (int) | Like (bit) | Dislike (bit) | Share (bit) | ...
1              1              1            NULL            NULL
1              2              NULL         1               NULL
1              3              1            NULL            1
```

The problem here is that if more actions can be taken on an item e.g. 'Favourited' then I have to add these columns to the table. This is breaking normalisation rules but it could work. The important business rule is that someone cannot `Like` and `Dislike` the same `Item` at the same time. Its one or the other. I guess I would have to do this logical processing on the application end rather than DB end but if there's a better way please do let me know!

The other approach could be to have a table that stores user actions like this:

```
ActionID | ActionName
1          Like
2          Dislike
3          Share
```

And then have a linking table like this:

```
UserID | ItemID | ActionID
1        1        1
1        1        2
1        1        3
```

The problem with this second approach is that I think it will be hard to make the Actions mutually exclusive. The user has Liked an item, and then Disliked it, and then Shared it. So in my application I would have to work out which ActionID relates to a Like or Dislike and then depending on which one is chosen, delete the other. So here I would have to delete the row with an ActionID value of '1' because it is overwritten by the Dislike action with value of '2'

Could anyone please advise on what the best way to do this might be? Its the mutual exclusivity between certain actions that is causing me the most bother.

Comment: Why would you want to delete an action?  Have a UserItemAction table with a date attached.  If you order by date desc you can the the actions the user performed on that item from most recent to oldest.

Comment: Why not have a single column representing Liked and it is either true or false?

Comment: @SpectralGhost Do you mean have one column called say "Opinion". Where 0 = dislike and 1 = like but a NULL means no response?

Comment: Yes, but personally I like to use Is as a preface on all boolean columns, so it becomes a truth. IsLiked=true or IsLiked=false. NULL is unknown/unanswered

Comment: @SpectralGhost If do that how do I count the difference between rows where IsLiked=True and IsLike=False

Comment: select sum(case when isliked=1 then 1 else 0 end) [Liked],sum(case when isliked=0 then 1 else 0 end) [Disliked] FROM table

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could re-implement it as an integer column and allow (-1, 0, 1) to represent (dislike, neutral, like), which in turn may simplify ranking an item's popularity. For example, to list the top 10 most liked items:

```
  select top (10)
         ItemID, sum(ToLikeOrNotLike)
    from Items
group by ItemID
order by sum(ToLikeOrNotLike) desc;
```

This takes cares of the mutual exclucivity as well.

## Alternative

On a suggestion from Spevy (see comments), the **0** (for no like or dislike) could be replaced with **null**, so that it's easier to determine overall activity on an item. For example:

```
  select top (10)
         ItemID, count(ToLikeOrNotLike)
    from Items
group by ItemID
order by count(ToLikeOrNotLike) desc;
```

Would return how many likes *or* dislikes an item has received. This can be useful to distinguish between an item with 2 likes and 1 dislikes, and an item with 10,000 likes and 9,999 dislikes, both of which would be otherwise indistinguishable when summed.

Comment: You don't need to convert it to an integer.  null = Absence of response 1 = Like, 0= Dislike.  The benefit is that if you need to do any aggregate calculations the null is ignored.

Comment: I only suggested the integer approach _because_ it makes aggregating easier. If space is a concern, a smaller type could be used instead, however from memory that might introduce overflow errors if an item has a lot of votes.

Comment: Matt fair point on the data type.  I would still recommend using a null value over a 0 value if there is no response.

Comment: That could be useful when determining activity on an item via `count(ToLikeOrNotToLike)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on your first idea of a table having Boolean columns for separate actions that the user has taken regarding the item.

Use a `CHECK` constraint on the table (change the table name to whatever your table is really named):

```
ALTER TABLE UserAction 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_LikeOrDisLike
CHECK (
    (Like is null AND Dislike is null)
    OR (Like = 1 AND Dislike is null)
    OR (Like is null AND Dislike = 1)
)
```

Or perhaps:

```
ALTER TABLE UserAction 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_LikeOrDisLike
CHECK (
    (ISNULL(Like, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(Dislike, 0) = 0)
    OR (Like = 1 AND ISNULL(Dislike, 0) = 0)
    OR (ISNULL(Like, 0) = 0 AND Dislike = 1)
)
```

if you want to allow `0 = false` in addition to `null = false`.

This could then further be changed to:

```
ALTER TABLE UserAction 
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_LikeOrDisLike
CHECK (
    ISNULL(Like, 0) = 0 OR ISNULL(Dislike, 0) = 0
)
```

This last one means that at least one of `Like` and `Dislike` must be either false or null.

This will of course not help you to make consistent updates from your program, you must still handle that separately. But **IF** your program tries to make an invalid insert or update, the database will reject it with an error message.